What's the requirement of the context of a handleable SIGSEGV on x86_64 Linux?
Is there any documentation on the requirement of the context of a SIGSEGV that can be handled by a user handler?
I'm particularly interested in the rsp register.
After I mmap or malloc a memory region and point the rsp register to it, memory faults will result in two SIGSEGVs that can't be handled:
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x12341234} ---
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_addr=NULL} ---

The second one seems to be a forced signal from the kernel. Is it the case that the kernel expect a certain stack size or a specific region of memory to be the stack? Here's my code:
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const ptrdiff_t shm_size = 4096 * 1024;
static ptrdiff_t shm_offset = 0;
static int shm_fd = -1;

void panic(char* s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t* info, void* _)
{
    uint64_t bad_addr = (uint64_t)info->si_addr;
    printf("Handling SIGSEGV at %p\n", bad_addr);

    void* new_page_addr = (void*)((bad_addr >> 12) << 12);
    printf("Maping new page %p\n", new_page_addr);
    if (MAP_FAILED == mmap(new_page_addr, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_FIXED | MAP_STACK , shm_fd, shm_offset)) {
        panic("mmap failed\n");
    }
    shm_offset += 4096;
    if (shm_offset > shm_size) {
        panic("overflow\n");
    }
}

void init_sigsegv_handler()
{
    shm_fd = shm_open("bb_shared_mem", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);
    if (shm_fd == -1) {
        panic("shm_open");
    }
    shm_unlink("bb_shared_mem");
    ftruncate(shm_fd, shm_size);
    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sigaction));
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL)) {
        panic("sigaction");
    }
}

extern void test_switch_stack(void * rsp);

int main()
{
    init_sigsegv_handler();
    char* stack = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    if (MAP_FAILED == stack) {
        panic("mmap\n");
    }
    // stack = malloc(4096);
    test_switch_stack(stack + 2048);
    printf("success\n");
    return 0;
}

.global test_switch_stack
.section .data

rsp_value: .quad 0

.section .text
test_switch_stack:
    mov %rsp, rsp_value
    mov %rdi, %rsp
    mov $0x12341234, %rdi
    movb $1, (%rdi)
    mov rsp_value, %rsp
    ret


printf() and mmap() are not safe to call in a signal handler; see https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html

And returning from a signal handler for SIGSEGV is undefined unless the signal was generated by kill(), sigqueue(), or raise().

@Shawn Even though the standard says returning is usually UB, doesn't the Linux kernel give a stronger guarantee that lets you safely do so in more circumstances? Consider, e.g., the libsigsegv project.
